# Instrumenting bytecode at method level

Tags: constants, code-coverage, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

```
if(iHandles[f].getInstruction() instanceof IFEQ  ) {
            getFieldInstruction = iHandles[f+1].getInstruction();
            System.out.println("found IF");
            InstructionList iprint = iFactory.createPrintln("The control is in IF");
            iList.setPositions();
            main.setMaxStack();
            main.setMaxLocals();
            main.removeLineNumbers();
            iList.insert(getFieldInstruction, iprint);
            main.setInstructionList(iList);

        }
```

In the above code I am instrumenting the bytecode at *if* statements.
I'm using constants like **IFEQ** or **IF_ICMPNE** to search for an *if* statement in a bytecode. 
I want to instrument the bytecode at every method. What constants can I use to do this ? Or how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works for *if* ... **`getFieldInstruction = iHandles[0].getInstruction();`**
to instrument methods.